# Suppose that $\pi \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ and that $\lambda(\pi)=p$ is a prime in $\mathbb{Z}$. Show that $\pi$ is a prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Suppose that $\pi \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ and that $\lambda(\pi)=p$ is a prime in $\mathbb{Z}$. Show that $\pi$ is a prime in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. Show that the corresponding result holds in $\mathbb{Z}[\omega]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-2}]$. [$\lambda$ is the Euclidean valuation i.e. $\lambda (a+bi) = a^2+b^2$]

To show $\pi$ is a prime I need to prove for any $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ whenever $\pi | \alpha \beta$ then $\pi | \alpha$ or $\pi | \beta$.

Now let, $$\pi | \alpha \beta \\
\implies \lambda(\pi) | \lambda(\alpha \beta) \\
\implies p | \lambda(\alpha) \lambda(\beta) \\
\implies p | \lambda(\alpha) \ \  or \ \ p | \lambda(\beta) $$.

But I'm completely stuck here. Can anyone help please?

Comment: I think it's a lot easier to use the fact that these rings are UFD's, so prime is the same as irreducible. Write $\pi = \alpha\beta$. Your argument then shows that $\lambda(\alpha) = 1$ or $\lambda(\beta)= 1$, i.e. that one of $\alpha, \beta$ is a unit.

Comment: @Mathmo123 you're right. This will do. But can you give a sketch of a proof if I want to do it independently?

Answer (score 1):

$\{\alpha, \beta\}={q_{\{\alpha, \beta\}}\pi + r_{\{\alpha, \beta\}}}$, where $0 \leq \lambda(r_{\{\alpha, \beta\}}) \leq \lambda ({\pi})/2$.

Since $\pi \mid \alpha\beta$, $\pi$ also divides $r_\alpha r_\beta$. Therefore $\lambda(\pi) \mid \lambda(r_\alpha)\lambda(r_\beta)$. However, since $\lambda(\pi)$ is a prime, one of $r_{\{\alpha, \beta\}}$ has to be $0$.

Comment: Although it uses a conclusion of the remainder (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer), it is elementary